# How can I detect a zoom end?

Tags: openlayers-3

Is there a good way to detect when the map's zoom animation has ended? OpenLayers used to raise the 'zoomend' event after the zoom had completed, but OpenLayers 3 doesn't have a corresponding event. I'm currently using the following approach, but it seems kludgy and brittle at best.

```
function main() {
  var map = ...;
  map.getView().on('change:resolution', handleResolutionChange);
}
function handleResolutionChange() {
  var map = ...;
  map.once('moveend', handleMoveEnd);
}
function handleMoveEnd() {
  setTimeout(handleZoomEnd, 0);
}
function handleZoomEnd() {
  //Handle the 'Zoom end' event
}
```

Answer (score 4):

did you try the `moveend` event on its own???? I have not try it but it should rise on zoomend as well. Also the `'change:resolution'` event is not documented. Does it really work??

try the following

```
var ghostZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
    map.on('moveend', (function() {
        if (ghostZoom != map.getView().getZoom()) {
            ghostZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
            console.log('zoomend');
        }
    }));
```

Comment: `moveend` on its own would also raise when the user pans the map. It is indeed raised when the map has finished zooming (that's why I'm using it after all), but also when I don't need it to. `change:resolution` is actually an event raised by ol.View. I misremembered when I typed the question

Comment: so why `map.getView().on('change:resolution', handleResolutionChange);` does not satisfy your case?

Comment: `change:resolution` is raised as soon as the resolution property changes, before the animations are completed

Comment: check my answer (edited with code snip). should work for your case

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been a while. I just want to share my idea.

```
    let isMapResolutionChanged;
    map.getView().on('change:resolution', () => {
        isMapResolutionChanged = true;
    });

    map.on('moveend', () => {
        if (isMapResolutionChanged) {
            console.log('fire moveend + zoomend')
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to share my solution because I stumbled over the same problem:

```
let zoomend = function(evt) {
  alert('zoomend on resolution: ' + evt.map.getView().getResolution());    
  evt.map.once('moveend', function(evt) {
    zoomend(evt);
  });
};
map.getView().once('change:resolution', function(evt) {
  map.once('moveend', function(evt) {
    zoomend(evt);
  });
});
```

Here the `change:resolution` event is only fired once at the beginning of a zoom action and is activated again when its finished.
You can have a look at a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srbfotaz/).